# Laplace's equation on a square domain with a central point reservoire

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Could someone please tell me the solution to this problem. I have $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$$ on the square domain $-L<x<L, -L<y<L$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions: $$u(L,y)=u(-L,y)=u(x,L)=u(x,-L)=0$$ and further condition $u(0,0)=1$.

I have tried separation of variables but quickly realised that it would only give me the trivial $u=0$.

This is not for some kind of homework, I am solving the heat equation numerically and would just like to know what the analytical steady state solution is so I may compare. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can this happen? Is $u$ a function $u(x,y)$ or is time $t$ involved: $u(x,y,t)$. If the latter is the case, then you must have some part of the equation that allows $u$ to evolve in time i.e. not the Laplace equation as stated. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the question. Sorry earlier I had the time dependence in there by accident. The solution I am looking for is time-independent.

Comment: As far as I know, such a solution cannot exist, because the solutions of a Laplace equation always assume their extreme values at the boundaries. So indeed the trivial $u=0$ will result: your $u(0,0)=1$ condition is not compatible. But perhaps what you mean is a delta function instead of zero as the right hand side of the Laplace equation? Giving a Poisson equation?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I think that $(0,0)$ would be considered the inner-boundary of the region in question, so that there may indeed be a compatible solution.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That's another possibility I have overlooked, indeed ..

Comment: Just a thought for another approach: perhaps we can modify the "further condition" to be $$u(\epsilon,y) = u(-\epsilon,y) = u(x,\epsilon) = u(x,-\epsilon) = 0$$ so that our domain of interest is a "square annulus", and take the limit of the solution as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.  I have no idea, however, whether such a solution would be "nice".

Comment: Yes I think something like this would be the best method in trying to solve the problem. I definitely think the condition $u(0,0)=1$ is an internal boundary condition we should consider shrunk down to a point in some limiting process.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It converges to $u\equiv 0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. The bottom line is, an isolated point is too small to matter for the Laplacian (in dimensions $\ge 2$), and an approximation procedure merely reaffirms that.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one solution to the problem 
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u =0 & \Omega, \\
u=0 & \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
when $\Omega$ is a domain with Lipschitz continuous boundary, such as the square. This solution is the identically vanishing one, as you can see in various ways; one of them is observing that the energy integral 
$$\int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u\rvert^2\, dx$$
must vanish.

Answer (score 0):

If $(0,0)$ is considered a boundary point, with $u(0,0)=1$ as a boundary condition, then there is  no solution of this boundary value problem  among the conditions. Indeed, a slightly generalized maximum principle says that if $u$ is a bounded harmonic function in a bounded domain  $\Omega$ and $u\le 0$ holds on $\partial \Omega$ except for finitely many points, then $u\le 0$ in $\Omega$.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/262974/127096) where rotational symmetry allows for an elementary proof that an isolated boundary point is not a *regular point* for the Dirichlet problem.

Answer (score -1):

The world of piecewise functions can have innovative possibilities.

You can introduce some jumping points in the normal continuous functions so that the derivatives of the modified functions do not change.

In fact the solution of this PDE can be $u(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{when}~x=y=0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ .