# the existence of solution of Laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

$\Omega=\mathbb{D}^{\star},\mathbb{D}^{\star}$ is open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$without zero.
is there a solution $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ of $\vartriangle u(x)=0,x\in\Omega,u(0)=1,u(x)=0,\|x\|=1$?

Comment: This is a duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262974/laplace-equation-dirichlet-problem-on-punctured-unit-ball/262987 An answer, together with discussion and necessary links.

Comment: thank you a lot. i think it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

No. From the [Maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle), solutions to Laplace's Equation must obtain their maximums and minimums along the boundary of their domain. So any solution that is 0 along the boundary must be 0 over the entire domain, which contradicts your condition of $u(0) = 1.$

Comment: Incidentally, I do not understand whpowell96's answer. The boundary of the domain $\Omega$ has two components: the unit circle (where $u$ is zero), and $\{0\}$ (where $u$ is one).

Comment: the boundary value is \{0,1\}，not {1}only